# How can I disable the onboard GPU on my laptop?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, switchable-graphics

I have a problem getting my computer to run a game. The problem is I can't run it by using my NVIDIA GPU. My computer insists on running it using the integrated GPU.

I tried some methods to force it to run on NVIDIA GPU - by going to NVIDIA control panel and choosing "Run that by using high performance NVIDIA GPU", but it doesnt work.

Is there a solution to disable my onboard GPU?

Comment: You could attempt to disable it in the BIOS, but without further information about what the model and other components are in the computer, it's difficult to say how to achieve what you want.

Comment: computer is asus n53sn-sz129v and i couldnt find an option on bios for that :S

Comment: I would look in windows power management and set it to performance.

Comment: no, it is already set on performance

Answer (score -1):

If the NVidia Graphics is comes with your Laptop which means NVidia is your on board graphics.
When we buy a laptop it comes with on board graphics of processor or graphic chipset but if seller say that laptop is having Nvidia/Radeon that means NVIDIA/Radeon is on board graphics

So, When you running a game then it is running Nvidia on board Graphics.

Thanks

Fardeen Saiyyed

Comment: This is incorrect. His laptop likely has a processor that includes on chip graphics like an Intel HD adapter AND dedicated graphics card like an NVIDIA or Radeon.

Comment: yea but when dedicated graphics come in laptop then at that time on board graphics doesn't come because it uses dedicated graphics as a primary graphice

Comment: It's called switchable graphics. Many laptops include this as a way of reducing power consumption when performing low intensity tasks.